# How to filter out non-integer and negative numbers from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter

i made a function that keep only the positive integer numbers inside an array and i want to know if there is a better way to write it, thank you

```js
var arr = [2, 5, 5.5, 3, 6.8, 0, -5];

const filtrate = (el) => {
  return Number.isInteger(el) && el > 0;
}

console.log(arr.filter(filtrate));
```

Comment: Looks perfect to me (though remember to polyfill `isInteger` for obsolete browsers)

Comment: I dont know if its better , but if you can use es6 syntax you could make it shorter i guess, and you could check with the typeof keyword.

Comment: @Kevin.a Though, `typeof` doesn't verify that the argument is an integer, only that it's a number, so that would require an additional check

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to parse the number as a Integer by using `parseInt()` and comparing it with the original value.

This will filter out floats as `parseInt` on a float will drop the decimal portion of the number. Works on older browsers too:

```js
var arr = [2, 5, 5.5, 3, 6.8, 0 , -5];

function filtrate(el) {
  return (parseInt(el, 10) === el) && el > 0;
}

console.log(arr.filter(filtrate));
```

Comment: Remember to use the radix, though ([`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)): `(parseInt(el, 10) === el)`; the likelihood of base-2, base-8 or base-16, numbers might be limited, but (usually) better safe than sorry.

Comment: @DavidThomas correct!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by 'better' - clearer or faster?

You probably want to check > 0 before checking whether it's integer, because converting to integer (particularly with ParseInt) could be slower.

It might be faster to try (el % 1 == 0) for your integer check.

```
var arr = [2, 5, 5.5, 3, 6.8, 0, -5];

function filtrate(el) {
  return el > 0 && el % 1 == 0;
}

console.log(arr.filter(filtrate));
```

Your original solution certainly looks reasonable - it all depends on whether you're expecting mostly integers, and what the size of your dataset is. And potentially on which browser you're expecting to run.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way using ES6 :

```js
const arr = [2, 5, 5.5, 3, 6.8, 0, -5]; //or use let instead of var
const filtrate = el => Number.isInteger(el) && el > 0;
console.log(arr.filter(filtrate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex`

```js
  const arr = [2, 1e3, 1.2e4, -1.2e4, 5, 5.5, 3, 6.8, 0, -5, { id: 1}, [1, 2, 4], -1.1, -33.45];
  
  const positiveInt = /^[1-9]\d*$/;
  const filtrate = (el) => {
    return typeof el === 'number' ? positiveInt.test(`${el}`) : false;
  };
  
  console.log(arr.filter(filtrate));
```